# How to end Redis monitoring

Tags: redis

In Redis there's a [MONITOR command](http://redis.io/commands/MONITOR) that is quite handy to watch all the commands that are being processed.

Once you've started monitoring, is there any way to stop monitoring from the same session?

If you kill the connection, does the monitoring end (as opposed to resource-intensive monitoring continuing on the server)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no API to do it - just close the connection.

The redis-cli command does not implement anything specific when the user hits CTRL-C to interrupt the program. Closing the connection should stop the monitoring.

Answer (score -1):

just press Ctrl + C

it will end redis-cli monitor.....